# How to display large list in the view without using database slicing?

Tags: grails, view, pagination, datatables, large-data

I have a service that generates a large map through multiple iterations and calculations from multiple tables. My problem is I cannot use pagination offset to slice the data because the data is coming from multiple tables and different modifications happen on the data. To display this on the screen; I have to send the map with 10-20,000 records to the view and that is problematic with this large dataset. 
At this time I have on-page pagination but this is very slow and inefficient. 
One thing I thought is to dump it on a table and query it each time but then I have to deal with concurrent users.

My question is what is the best approach to display this list when I cannot use database slicing (offset, max)?

I am using 
grails 1.0.3
datatables and jquery

Comment: Can you generate a view in the database to represent the data?  Or use some sort of caching mechanism, like *Redis*?  You absolutely need to be able to support pagination/slicing to work with that much data.  Web browsers just aren't designed to handle that much information at once.  It think your biggest issue is you need to rethink your design or method of representing the data.

Comment: Redis plugin is for grails 1.3.4 and beyond, my grails version is 1.0.3. I can create a temp tables but then shouldn't I need to worry about the concurrent users? cleaning up the data? managing the each request? I am not sure if that is the right path to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [SlickGrid!](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/) is an option for you. One of there [examples](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) works with 50000 rows and it seems to be fast.

Christian

Answer (score 0):

I end up writing the result of the map in a table and use the data slicing on that table for pagination. It takes some time to save the data but at least I don't have to worry about the performance with the large data.  I use time-stamp to differentiate between requests. each requests will be saved and retrieved with its time stamp.